# How to create more than one source folders programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create more than one source folder in a java project programmatically.Now I am able to create one source folder with the java project .But if I give more than one like /src/main/java & /src/test/java .
[image]

It is creating like above picture.
I am using below code for creating source folders in java project.

```
 for (String srcPath : projectSrcPath.split("\\s+")) {
final IClasspathEntry[] buildPath = { JavaCore.newSourceEntry(project.getFullPath().append(srcPath)),
                        JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry() };

javaProject.setRawClasspath(buildPath, project.getFullPath().append("bin"), null);
createFolder(project.getFullPath().append(srcPath));
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all source folders to `buildPath`. Simply create more entries with `JavaCore.newSourceEntry()` plus the correct path.

Don't forget to create all the folders!

Comment: Thank you @Aaron Digulla.I'll try with adding all source folders to buil path.Can u please some example of 2nd option?

Comment: @Anu Just look at the last line of the code sample you posted in your question!?